# How to log clicking on a URL button in InlineKeyboardMarkup (python-telegram-bot)

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

**Summarize the problem**

I have created an inline keyboard markup in a Telegram bot using python-telegram-bot as below.

```
keyboard = [
[InlineKeyboardButton(" view website" , url='<some_url>')],
[InlineKeyboardButton(" add a new organization", callback_data='addorganizations')],
[InlineKeyboardButton(" add a new person", callback_data='addmembers')],
[InlineKeyboardButton("❔ guide", callback_data='guide')],
[InlineKeyboardButton(" exit", callback_data='kill')]
]
```

Callback buttons can be logged if clicked. I use the following line of code to do so.

```
"""Audit & Log"""
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

async def help(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user = update.callback_query.from_user
    logger.info("User %s ran the help command & read the guide.", user.full_name)
```

But what if a user clicks on a URL button? how can we log this kind of activity?

**What I have tried**

I know it sounds stupid but I tried to assign a `callback_data` to url buttons as well. No wonder it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Inline buttons with a `URL` don't produce a `CallbackQuery`, i.e. your bot is not informed about the user pressing the button. Your best bet is to use a URL redirect, e.g. `url=http://yourdomain.com/<some_id>`, where opening `http://yourdomain.com/<some_id>` does two things:

1. inform your bot that the user pressed the button
2. redirects the user to the actual URL

Comment: This should be done with Telegram.WebApp.sendData() right? Are web apps called from an InlineButton able to handle that?

Comment: This is independent of webapps. If you open a webapp (instead of a generic website) it's ofc easier to know for your bot.